# How to create and send ZIP archive from C# to Python and save to filesystem?

Tags: c#, python, zip

In C# I create zip archive with some files:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipStorer zip = ZipStorer.Create(ms, "comment"))
    {
        zip.EncodeUTF8 = true;
        foreach (FileInfo logFile in logFiles)
        {
            zip.AddFile(ZipStorer.Compression.Deflate, logFile.FullName, logFile.Name, "");
        }
    }
    this.logger.log("memory stream to array");
    zipBytesArr = ms.ToArray();
}
```

It works, because when I persist zip archive on server with C# - I can open it.

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\test.zip", zipBytesArr);
```

Now I send it as bytes array `zipBytesArr` in POST request, I create object with field type `byte[]`, than serialise it to `JSON` and send.

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
{
    // .. some fields
    ZipFileBytesArr = ZipFileBytesArr
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
```

Now I want to get it in Python 3 (flask), I got some long string and I want to create zip archive. My question is: how to achieve this?

I tried something like this:

```
bytes_as_str = "UEsDBBQAAAgIACyrWk4qVSmD0gYAAA4WAAAYAAAAMjAxOTAyMjZfb3BlbnZ...."
bytes_as_bytes = bytes_as_str.encode(encoding="utf-8")
file = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(bytes_as_bytes))
```

and it does not work, I got an error:

```
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: So you're taking a whole object and serializing it, but want to decompress only the file - don't you want to only serialize/encode `ZipFileBytesArr`? Otherwise it looks like you're expecting the whole serialized object to contain only the bytes of the ZIP file.

Comment: That string looks like Base64-encoded data. Try decoding it with a Base64 decoder (can't help you with that; you will have to consult the Python documentation by yourself), and try using/opening the decoded result as a Zip archive...

Comment: @RandomDavis I serialise the whole object to JSON, than in Python I take part of this JSON, just like this ```request.json['zipFile']``` and then I try to persist this bytes array to zip file on filesystem,

Comment: @elgonzo you are right! it is base64! please write it as an answer and I will mark it. Now I want to understand in what exactly moment, C# represents bytes array as base64 string... I will research.

Comment: @dikkini, since i don't know how the Base64 decoding would be done on the Python side, i would like to refrain from writing an answer, because in my opinion just writing something like "_That string looks like Base64-encoded data. Decode it with a Base64 decoder_" would be a rather poor low-quality answer. If you want to share your Python code for Base64 decoding in an answer (yes, you can write an answer to your own question), then this could perhaps be helpful to others who also struggle with Base64 decoding in Python.

Comment: By the way, it is the Json serializer - Newtonsoft.Json, i suspect - who converts the byte array into a Base64 string. See here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm

Comment: @elgonzo and you are right again. thank you. please write an answer and I will mark it.